# Why isn't my RecyclerView displaying my adapter items?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So i have a recycler view that is designed to show users sending messages to each other from my Firebase RTD. Originally it was working to show all users and the recycler items were clicked then it would show messages between the users. However, when modifying it to only view users that were in open messages with the current user, the items that populated my recycler view no longer displays and an error saying `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` is logged within the Run tab.

Unfortunately i can no longer undo the changes and have struggled to find the cause of my problem but have assume that it is either taking place in my adapted or activity classes.

InboxActivity.java:

```
public class InboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<User> inboxLst;

    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    UserAdapter usrAdpt;

    private List<String> userLst;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);

        //Identify and setup recycler view
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rycInbox);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        userLst = new ArrayList<>();

        //Get all chats between current user and and other users
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userLst.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snp.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (chat.getSender().equals(user.getUid())){
                        userLst.add(chat.getReceiver());
                    }
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(user.getUid())){
                        userLst.add(chat.getSender());
                    }
                }
                readChat();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readChat() {
        inboxLst = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userLst.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User usr = snp.getValue(User.class);

                    //Display users that are currently in an open chat
                    for (String id : userLst){
                        if(usr.getId().equals(id)){
                            if(inboxLst.size() != 0){
                                for (User usrl : inboxLst){
                                    if(!usr.getId().equals(usrl.getId())){
                                        inboxLst.add(usr);
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                inboxLst.add(usr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Set the adapter for the recycler view once using the chat information retrieved from firebase database
                usrAdpt = new UserAdapter(InboxActivity.this,inboxLst);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(usrAdpt);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }
}
```

UserAdapter.java:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context cont;
    private List<User> nUser;

    public UserAdapter(Context cont, List<User> nUser){
        this.cont = cont;
        this.nUser = nUser;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(cont).inflate(R.layout.lst_layout_inbox, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = nUser.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());

        holder.usrLst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(cont, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userid",user.getId());
                cont.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nUser.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView username;
        RelativeLayout usrLst;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usrName);
            usrLst = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usrCard);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try these things:
- Set the adapter in onCreate.
- and in the ondatachanged listener, update the ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged()

This should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only catchup in your question is, in the following method:

```
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         userLst.clear(); // <------ WHY YOU CLEAR LIST HERE??? COMMENT THIS ----------
         for (DataSnapshot snp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             User usr = snp.getValue(User.class);

              //Display users that are currently in an open chat
              for (String id : userLst){
                  if(usr.getId().equals(id)){
                      if(inboxLst.size() != 0){
                          for (User usrl : inboxLst){
                              if(!usr.getId().equals(usrl.getId())){
                                  inboxLst.add(usr);
                               }
                           }
                       }else{
                           inboxLst.add(usr);
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
            //Set the adapter for the recycler view once using the chat information retrieved from firebase database
            usrAdpt = new UserAdapter(InboxActivity.this,inboxLst);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(usrAdpt);
       }
```

why you do `userLst.clear();` ?

Since in `OnCreate()` method you populate **userLst** and call `readChat()`. And in `onDataChange()` you *clear* the **userLst** and then afterwards you try to iterate over the **userLst** to Display users that are currently in an open chat.

I would suggest to comment this  `userLst.clear();` and after setting items call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Wow what a clumsy mistake. I must not have removed that line of code when i was modifying the code and as you said it must have been iterating an empty list

Comment: @Ezan glad that your issue is resolved :) and you are correct you were iterating over empty list.

Comment: Thank you very much mate! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

- Set the adapter in onCreate.
- and in the onDataChanged listener, update the ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged().

This should help

Comment: i'm sorry i don't have the most java knowledge. So to set the adapter should i move the the one that is in the bottom of my  `readChat onDataChange` to the onCreate. And im not too sure how to update an ArrayList